# Using exists in a query instead of a regular where

Tags: syntax

I saw this query that finds all the employees with more than one degree:

```
select id, name
from employee E
where exists (
 select *
 from academics A1, academics A2
 where  A1.emp_id = E.id and
        A2.emp_id = E.id and
        A1.discipline != A2.discipline
 )
```

But why is the `exists` necessary? Why not just do:

```
select id, name
from employee E, academics A1, academics A2
where A1.emp_id = E.id and
      A2.emp_id = E.id and
      A1.discipline != A2.discipline
```

Are the two above equivalent?

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: @McNets not using any live dbms so, pen and paper.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent. The first is a semijoin. The second is a join. It can give (the 2nd) more rows in the result.

Comment: More duplicate rows? @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: Yes, the rows would be duplicated (actually multiplied, depending on the values in `academics`).

Comment: Also, of course, the second query may immediately fail. If `academics` has a column named `id` or `name`, the query will not know which table those columns in the select list come from.

Comment: At a minimum: every employee who shows up would show up twice, Example. Sam Jones has a degree in Physics and a degree in Chemistry. His ID will show up twice, because it will match when A1 is Physics and A2 is Chemistry, and when A1 is Chemistry and A2 is Physics.

Comment: Note: my comment was explicitly supposed to be an expansion of @ypercube's note on duplicate or more, explaining the whys of it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you another approach.

`COUNT DISTINCT` disciplines by employee.

Then use `EXISTS` to check if one Employee has more than one degree.

```
select      e.id, e.name
from        Employees e
where exists (select    1
              from      Academics a
              where     a.emp_id = e.id
              having count(distinct a.discipline) > 1);
```

Or JOIN it with table Employees and show these were NumDegrees > 1

```
select      e.id, e.name, nd.NumDegrees
from        Employees e
inner join (select    emp_id, count(distinct a.discipline) NumDegrees
            from      Academics a
            group by  a.emp_id) nd
on          e.id = nd.emp_id
where       nd.NumDegrees > 1;
```

Comment: What's `select 1`?

Comment: Exists simply evaluate if sentence returns rows. https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: never mind I totally missed that. (you gotta add the group by back.) =(

Comment: @EvanCarroll you're right, http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=844eb3a04070eb337eaa006d12e231dd

Comment: That's only because SQL server accepts unstandardized syntax. You still need the `group by` it's just implicit there.

Comment: @EvanCarroll the syntax is fine with and without the `GROUP BY` there. Standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I'd add one more variant, which might clearer for somebody, and which any decent optimizer would consider equivalent to the second one proposed by McNets:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
  FROM Employees e
 WHERE e.id IN (SELECT a.emp_id
                          FROM Academics a
                          GROUP BY a.emp_id
                          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.discipline) > 1);
```

Comment: I disagree on the "it's really a waste". It might perform better or worse than your versions, depending on many things.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Well, more often than not, it is better to avoid self joins if you can. However, you are right in the general case and I deleted the sentence with which you disagreed.